# How to style nav drop down menus with dark gradient instead of white?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to apply a class or a custom style to make a white nav drop down menu look like this gradient tooltip from bootstrap, http://www.bootply.com/68688 (hover over the link) instead of taking the plain old white background?

If so how can this be accomplished?

Comment: Let me know if you looked at the fiddle and saw how I styled the dropdown to have a dark black to dark gray gradient to make sure I know if I got your question correctly, otherwise to edit my answer.

Comment: @sulfureous: Good stuff.  You definitely made the correct assumptions and gaps with my ambiguity.  =)  Awesome stuff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to understand the question, but I think that if I'm on the same page with you, you want the nav's dropdown to be with any other color instead of white.

I would definitively suggest here that when something doesn't ship with bootstrap it doesn't mean you can't extend it with your own stylesheet.

Make sure you add your styles at the bottom of all the other styles (preferably in a new stylesheet so you don't modify the stock bootstrap files).

Here's a Fiddle of the dropdown with black instead of white.

**jsFiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/rYUfq/)**

Notice how I added `.mainNav` to the `<ul class="nav nav-tabs">` in order to have a specific hook to this navigation in case you don't want your styles to cascade to all the drop down's on your site.

The main thing here is to remember that just because it doesn't ship stock with bootstrap doesn't mean you can't extend it... it's good to try to look for stock, but if you can't find it then make it, and make it so in an organized way.

Last but not least, I think it's also note worthy to say that, yes... There are some cases where you can use the `.navbar-inverse` class (such as to make a black navbar) or in buttons `.btn-inverse`, but in this particular case I don't think that bootstrap ships with anything that will let you invert the color for that specific element.

Comment: Fantstic! Right on the $. Very nice sulfereous!  QQ: so I add that new style in my custom.css....but do I need to load that before or after teh bootstrap.css?

Comment: Load it after... this way your custom CSS is the latest CSS parsed and the latest style applied. If you ever add some CSS and Bootstrap keeps overwriting it when you look in your code inspector then it means that you have to be much more specific with your selector.